# Increasing UITableView tranparency as it's scrolled beyond edge of content

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to replicate a cool UI feature that the app Snapchat has. When you scroll past the normal height of the table view, the more you scroll up the more transparent the cells become, as shown in the attached image. Currently, I have a background image behind my table view, and scrolling the table beyond the edge of its content reveals part of that image. However, what I don't know is how to make the table cells become progressively more transparent as one scrolls the table further. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you aware of the `UIView` property `alpha`? How about the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is the way I approached using @Vijay_07's answer:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Fades out top and bottom cells in table view as they leave the screen
    NSArray *visibleCells = [self.tableView visibleCells];

    CGPoint offset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    CGRect bounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    CGSize size = self.tableView.contentSize;
    UIEdgeInsets inset = self.tableView.contentInset;
    float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
    float h = size.height;


    if (y > h) {
        self.tableView.alpha = 1 - (y/h - 1)*4;
        for (UITableViewCell *cell in visibleCells) {
            cell.contentView.alpha = 1 - (y/h - 1)*4;
        }
    } else {
        for (UITableViewCell *cell in visibleCells) {
            cell.contentView.alpha = 1;
        }
        self.tableView.alpha = 1;
    }
}
```

Meanwhile:

1) in your storyboard make sure you use a UIImageView below the table

2) in the viewDidLoad do this:

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SAMEIMAGE HERE!!.png"]];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView: myImage];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self scrollViewDidScroll:self.tableView];
```

3) in your .h add `<UIScrollViewDelegate>`

and you should be fine.

Comment: thats great, but how do i make it so that it only happens when you get to bottom of the tableiew and try to keep dragging but it dosn't work and you see the image behind, but the more you force it to go down the more the cells become transparent.

Comment: this does exactly that

Comment: in the code it says self.table.alpha I'm getting an error on the "table" is says that the property "table" is not found on object type ViewController, so i replaced it with tableView and it works but it starts to become transparent when i start to scroll whats the issue?

Comment: so this worked for ios6 but now in ios7 all im getting is completely transparent cells when i load my tableview? any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can use property alpha to create transparent view.

use 
`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)` ScrollView when scrolling starts change the alpha value, set alpha value to tableview or cell. set delegate for table view  before proceeding.

for cell you can set alpha value like this `cell.contentView.alpha=0.2;` I hope this could solve if any mistake am glade to see where i did mistake